# Bootstrap 3.3.5 disable prev next buttons in product carousel

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am working on a small project and also new to bootstrap. I am stuck at product carousel controls to be disabled (not hide) when on item:first & item:last class has active state. It is similar to E-commerce site slider.

Here is my code: http://www.bootply.com/T7KihOPj2R

Comment: Check the DOC, there is an option for that: `data-wrap="false"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either set data-wrap="false" on the carousel

or

just put it in the options when you initialize the carousel.

For refrence you can go through the [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/Zu0eWqXHp9)

Comment: Thanks for the demo but I have prev next buttons which will be placed outside the carousel so I need them in disable state and not hidden. Added wrap: false in jquery but it wont stop till last item is all the way in left.

here is the link: http://www.bootply.com/apIkr5NzSS